# Can I create mysql view columns from an array?

Tags: php, mysql

The array is json_encoded and stored in another table. Now I want to create a mysql View with MERGE type, and json_decode the array into the View's columns. Is this possible? If yes, How?

Comment: So, what do you mean with `MERGE`? The table engine or the SQL merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to do that stuff NOT in the database and just use PHP it will be easy. You just have to select the encoded array, decode it, parse it to columns (or any valid SQL), store it in an string and perform this SQL string, than you have what you want.

```
$sql_array = 'select json_array from tbl';
//use mysql-query/fetch/execute whatever to get your data
//use json_encode to get your PHP $columns = array()
$columns = json_encode(...);

$sql_cols = 'select null';
//iterate through your PHP array()
foreach($columns as $column) {
  //make the row-value to columns
  $sql_cols .= ', '.$column;
}
$sql_cols .= ' from tbl';
//use mysql-query/fetch/execute whatever to get your data
```

This should do it.